# How in Unity of action of the button to attach to AR-objects (ImageTarget)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

There are several `ImageTargets`, and there are three buttons in the interface, when you click, the sound plays (voicing in three languages). How can I attach an action to `ImageTarget`?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by attaching an action to ImageTarget? Do you want to play the sound when image is detected or do you want to play the voice when button is pressed? If it is second option what does it have to do with image targets?

Comment: When you press a button

Comment: Then it has nothing to do with the image Target is not it? You have three buttons play 1 voice for 1 button. I did not understand the augmented reality part of this.

Comment: Yes it is. but I have several images, for each a separate voice. For example: there are 2 images, and there are 2 buttons (in English and in Spanish), when you hover over the first picture, the sounds for the first picture should be reproduced

Comment: for one button there should be several tracks for different scenes

Comment: Okay i understand now the sounds are supposed to be played based on image targets. Each image target has an `ID` in your database. You can check the `ID` of the image target and play sound accordingly.

Comment: Nobody can give you a real answer unless you give us more details. Update your question with clarification on what it is exactly that you want to achieve, what you've tried before, and what SDK you are using. At the very least.